Juniper EX4650 unable to connect to anything
I have recently ran into a problem, where I have tried setting up routing from interface vme to our gateway and for some reason it is unable to ping or connect to anything.
What I have tried:

Confirmed the network cable is functional and allows the access I want.
Made sure there is no firewall rules or security rules blocking the way.
Double checked my configurations to make sure all seems well.
Made sure the interface is up and connected (the port or such isn't damaged)

Configuration:
show route output:
inet.0: 3 destinations, 3 routes (3 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
 + = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both
 + List item

0.0.0.0/0*[Static/5] 01:12:09
> to 10.69.69.69 via vme.0


10.69.69.0/24*[Direct/0] 01:13:21
> via vme.0

10.69.69.140/32*[Local/0] 01:13:21
Local via vme.0

inet6.0: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)

+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

ff02::2/128 *[INET6/0] 02:07:37
MultiRecv

Interface vme Config:
description "Virtual Management Port";
unit 0 {
  family inet {
    address 10.69.69.140/24;
  }
}

show routing-options output:
static {
  route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 10.69.69.69;
}

Also, I checked system name-servers and it has a legitimate name server though I don't think that would affect direct ip pinging.
If anyone can see anything that looks off or incorrect feel free to let me know. I am at my wits end right now.

The issue was I had the ethernet plugged into c0 on the backup switch instead of the master switch (had them mislabeled and was only using 1 cable as it was for testing).
